# Very Simple Routing on One page website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a simple one page website, where the pages scroll horizontally using the scrollTo() javascript library. I have a home / about / contact page. I was wondering if there was a way to still use some form of URL routing like www.example.com/about, to get the about page, and would get updated in the browser when the page was clicked in the navigation.

Comment: sounds like you don't have a one page website, if you have home/about/contact...can you clarify?

Comment: Take a look at how jquery mobile drives its hashing model: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your easiest bet is going to be to use hashes. i.e. `www.example.com/#about`

You can then use `window.history` [(more reading)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history) in order to change the URL without a page reload. Specifically, you will be looking for history.pushState() or history.replaceState()

Depending on what browser support you need, you might need something like [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) to fall back in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the page with [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)